# C#: creating an array and appending console input to each value

Tags: c#, arrays, input, console

I'm seeking a solution for the inline commented out steps... I am able to run this, enter text in console and see it append to the 0 index value but the console input is not then also following the expected for loop - all help is much appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A one-dimensional array of strings.
        string[] baseballTeams = { "Mariners", "Giants", "Angels", "Dodgers" };

        // Ask the user to input some text.
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter some text.");

        // A loop that iterates through each string in the array and adds the user's text input to the end of each string.
        // This step will not output anything to the console, but will update each array element by appending the user's text.
        for (int i = 0; i < baseballTeams.Length; i++)
        {
            string toArray = baseballTeams[i] + Console.ReadLine();
            baseballTeams[i] = toArray;

            // Then create a second loop that prints off each string in the array one at a time.
            foreach (string team in baseballTeams)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(team);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I've tried this code and run it in console, entering text, and seeing some append to the 0 index, but am not seeing it cascade out to the other array indexes.

Comment: *"but am not seeing it cascade out to the other array indexes"* - It's not clear to me what you mean by that.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Hi David,

There are no bugs when debugging - when entering say a bunch of c's in console, it solely appends to the 0 index value of the array ("Mariners"), like this:

Please enter some text.
ccccccccccccc
Marinersccccccccccccc
Giants
Angels
Dodgers

Comment: I've copied the code and tested it locally, and it does exactly what I expect it to do.  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *"There are no bugs when debugging"* - Do you mean that the code does what you expect when debugging?  Then what are you asking?  If you're expecting the line `baseballTeams[i] = toArray;` to update every array index, and not **just** the array index at `i`... why?

Comment: I mean that I have run the debugging tool in Visual Studio and it states the build is successful and generates no bugs. With the for loop, the expected behavior is for the console input to be appended to each array value.

Comment: Your problem is where you read the console input. You read it in the loop, the first time through the loop there is input, but each time after the input is gone as it was taken in the first loop. The console input does sit there for ever. You need to put the console input in a variable before the loop and then use the variable that contains the input within in your loop as you append to each array element.

Comment: *"it states the build is successful and generates no bugs"* - Visual Studio has no way of knowing what you **expect** your code to do.  Don't rely on it to tell you if your code is intuitively correct or not.  Insisting that "there are no bugs" while asking how to solve a bug in the code is counter-productive.  *"the expected behavior is for the console input to be appended to each array value"* - After you enter text and press return, what happens when you enter text **again** and press return **again**?  Did you just forget to keep testing the logic?

Comment: @David thanks for understanding some people are new to this and need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // A one-dimensional array of strings.
        string[] baseballTeams = { "Mariners", "Giants", "Angels", "Dodgers" };

        // Ask the user to input some text.
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter some text.");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        // A loop that iterates through each string in the array and adds the user's text input to the end of each string.
        // This step will not output anything to the console, but will update each array element by appending the user's text.
        for (int i = 0; i < baseballTeams.Length; i++)
        {
            baseballTeams[i] = baseballTeams[i] + userInput;    
        }

        // Then create a second loop that prints off each string in the array one at a time.
        foreach (string team in baseballTeams)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(team);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This accepts one user input and adds it to each element inside baseballTeams array. If you wanted to have the user input some text for each team you would move `string userInput = Console.ReadLine();` inside the `for` loop

You also needed to move `foreach` loop outside of the `for` loop otherwise you would have printed out the array 4 times.

Comment: I see - thank you so much! Steep learning curve and appreciate the help in becoming unstuck :-)

Comment: Brilliant, glad I could help, and yes there is certainly a steep learning curve! From the comments to your question it seems like you dont quite understand the difference from complier errors, runtime errors , and bugs.
Simply put a bug is your code doing something 'unwanted', a complier error is for example visual studio telling you the code you wrote is wrong and it cant understand it, and a runtime error is during execution the code something causes an error. It is worth doing more reading up on each of these. Also if this answer has helped could you please accept it as the answer!